# Old variable speed AC motor wiring

Tags: motor, transformer

As a disclaimer, I have a little electronics knowledge, but I'm no expert.  I've been given an old 1940's Hunter fan and I'm working on fixing it up.  I took the base apart and wiring is pretty bad - cracked and bare in places...  I'm going to replace it, but I'd like to understand what is going on -- how the variable speed works.

I've drawn a crappy diagram based on the wiring I see -- can anyone explain it?

[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: There is an error on your switch diagram? Usually black=hot, white=neutral, green=ground and red=hot (dimmed). What are the 3 functions? OFF-LO-HI or LO-HI-REVERSE?

Comment: @rjobidon a small point: just to clarify "usually black=hot" etc ... means "usually in America". We wouldn't want readers elsewhere in the world assuming this referred to their own wiring...

Comment: @rjobidon There might be an error - the switch speed functions are: high (green), medium (yellow & green to motor) and low (blue), and off (not shown)